# How to continually call a function using NSThread in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm writing a program for parsing xml file I need to continually read the file that means if any change happens to the xml file at run time it must shown in the simulator also 
I tried

```
 NSThread *myThread =[[NSThread alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(doParsing) object:nil];
    [myThread start];
```

and it calls the xml file but its not showing the change .How can I achieve that

Comment: did u save the change?

Comment: yep I did save the change

Comment: `while(1) { function(); }`, perhaps?

Comment: You want continually call a function , why not use `NSTimer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly something like:

```
NSThread *myThread =[[NSThread alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(callTimer) object:nil];
[myThread start];

- (void)callTimer
{
   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0
    target:self
    selector:@selector(doParsing)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:YES];
}

- (void)doParsing
{
   //Do the stuff here
}
```

Comment: I tried your method but it didn't calling the doParsing

Comment: @AlenJoy: In my method it'll call the doParsing after every ten seconds. Change that time and put a log on doParsing